# execute command on remote windows machine using libssh

Tags: ssh, libssh, remotecommand

I tried executing a shell command on a remote linux host using `libssh` and it worked. I followed the example from their [tutorial](http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_command.html) . But when tried on a windows remote host, it didn't work (I changed the command of course). So my question is: is it possible to execute a remote command on a windows host?

**EDIT:**

```
int show_remote_files(ssh_session session){
ssh_channel channel;
int rc;
channel = ssh_channel_new(session);
if (channel == NULL) return SSH_ERROR;
rc = ssh_channel_open_session(channel);
if (rc != SSH_OK)
 {
  ssh_channel_free(channel);
  return rc;
 }
rc = ssh_channel_request_exec(channel, "dir");
if (rc != SSH_OK)
 {
ssh_channel_close(channel);
ssh_channel_free(channel);
return rc;
 }
char buffer[256];
int nbytes;
nbytes = ssh_channel_read(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
while (nbytes > 0)
{
  if (fwrite(buffer, 1, nbytes, stdout) != nbytes)
  {
    ssh_channel_close(channel);
    ssh_channel_free(channel);
    return SSH_ERROR;
  }
  nbytes = ssh_channel_read(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
}
if (nbytes < 0)
{
  ssh_channel_close(channel);
  ssh_channel_free(channel);
  return SSH_ERROR;
}
```

And by it didn't work I meant I had no response from the server.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code, and describe in in detail what happens when you run it. Don't just say "it didn't work".

Comment: Well I think the question is pretty much clear, "So my question is, is it possible to execute a remote command on a windows host? " (Using libssh of course) 
The source code I used is from the one from the link I posted, but I will copy/paste.
I hope you have an answer after seeing the code.

Comment: So, your code runs to completion, but "dir" doesn't produce any output? Is that correct? Or are you getting an error somewhere? If you're getting an error, what line is producing it and exactly what does the message say?

Comment: @Kenster The code runs to completion and dir does not produce any output. I guess the issue is with the ssh server. I implemented a client and a server with pyhton using paramiko and it works fine ( Able to execute windows commands remotely). I will try to implement my own ssh server using libssh.